Let E be a normed space and S a non-zero element of the dual space of E. Then S is an open mapping.
Since $S \in E^{'}$ is non-zero, there exists an element $x_{0} \in E$ such that $S(x_0) \neq 0$. To show that $S$ is an open mapping, I considered the ball centered at $x_0$ with radius epsilon $B(x_{0},\varepsilon) \subset E$. It suffices to prove that $S(B(x_{0},\varepsilon))$ is open. (I believe that, due to linearity, it is enough to show that the image of the ball centered at zero is open, but I am not entirely sure.)
To prove that $S(B(x_{0},\varepsilon))$ is open, I only need to find a ball centered at some point in R such that $B(f(x_{0}),r) \subset S(B(x_{0},\varepsilon))$. However, I am struggling to determine the radius r that should be chosen to ensure this is true.

This is well known and proved in Rudin's FA.

(you don't say, but it seems you assume your spaces are real; the complex version of this argument is only slightly harder)
Any nonzero linear functional, continuous or not, is open.
As you say, because of linearity you can scale and translate, so it is enough to show that $S(B (0,1))$ is open. Fix $\lambda=S (y)$, with $\|y\|<1$. Choose $z\in B (0,1)$ with $\|z\|<1-\|y\|$ and $S(z)\ne0$ (if $S$ is zero in a ball around zero then it is zero). Then $y+rz\in B (0,1)$ for all $r\in(-1,1)$. Suppose $S(z)>0$ (otherwise, use $-z$). Then $r\longmapsto S (y+rz)=\lambda+rS(z)$ maps $(-1,1)$ to $(\lambda-S(z),\lambda+S (z))\subset S (B (0,1))$.

Indeed. The argument does use that $S$ is nonzero, but I should have mentioned it explicitly.

I was just being a pendant:-)
